# Notice: Undefined offset: 3,4,5,6,7,8

Tags: php, html, css

```
811.<div style="position:absolute; left:15.5%; top:108%;"> <img src="../../fb_users/<?php echo $gender; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>/Profile/<?php echo $img_array[0] ?>" height="90" width="78">  </div>
812.<div style="position:absolute; left:22%; top:108%;"> <img src="../../fb_users/<?php echo $gender; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>/Post/<?php echo $img_array[1] ?>" height="90" width="78">  </div>
813.<div style="position:absolute; left:28.5%; top:108%;"> <img src="../../fb_users/<?php echo $gender; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>/Post/<?php echo $img_array[2] ?>" height="90" width="78">  </div>
814.<div style="position:absolute; left:15.5%; top:125%;"> <img src="../../fb_users/<?php echo $gender; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>/Post/<?php echo $img_array[3] ?>" height="90" width="78">  </div>
815.<div style="position:absolute; left:22%; top:125%;"> <img src="../../fb_users/<?php echo $gender; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>/Post/<?php echo $img_array[4] ?>" height="90" width="78">  </div>
816.<div style="position:absolute; left:28.5%; top:125%;"> <img src="../../fb_users/<?php echo $gender; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>/Post/<?php echo $img_array[5] ?>" height="90" width="78">  </div>
817.<div style="position:absolute; left:15.5%; top:142%;"> <img src="../../fb_users/<?php echo $gender; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>/Post/<?php echo $img_array[6] ?>" height="90" width="78">  </div>
818.<div style="position:absolute; left:22%; top:142%;"> <img src="../../fb_users/<?php echo $gender; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>/Post/<?php echo $img_array[7] ?>" height="90" width="78">  </div>
819.<div style="position:absolute; left:28.5%; top:142%;"> <img src="../../fb_users/<?php echo $gender; ?>/<?php echo $user; ?>/Post/<?php echo $img_array[8] ?>" height="90" width="78">  </div>
```

**ERRORS:**
**( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp64\www\peppal\fb_files\fb_profile\Profile.php on line 814 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0017384336{main}( )...\Profile.php:0 " height="90" width="78">**

**( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\wamp64\www\peppal\fb_files\fb_profile\Profile.php on line 815 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0017384336{main}( )...\Profile.php:0 " height="90" width="78">**

**( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp64\www\peppal\fb_files\fb_profile\Profile.php on line 816 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0017384336{main}( )...\Profile.php:0 " height="90" width="78">**

**( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\wamp64\www\peppal\fb_files\fb_profile\Profile.php on line 817 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0017384336{main}( )...\Profile.php:0 " height="90" width="78">**

**( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\wamp64\www\peppal\fb_files\fb_profile\Profile.php on line 818 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0017384336{main}( )...\Profile.php:0 " height="90" width="78">**

**( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in C:\wamp64\www\peppal\fb_files\fb_profile\Profile.php on line 819 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0017384336{main}( )...\Profile.php:0 " height="90" width="78">**

Comment: And where's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if a variable is existing or not, you code should be like,

```
print isset($img_array[3]) && '<div style="position:absolute; left:15.5%; top:125%;">
        <img src="../../fb_users/'.$gender.'/'.$user.'/Post/'.$img_array[3].'" 
         height="90" width="78"></div>';
```

Use same code for other array indexes.